# Distribution Provisioning profile not creating properly?

Tags: ios, xcode5, code-signing, provisioning-profile

Hi when i run my project with development Provisioning profile it was working fine.So Today i tried to create a new Distribution provisioning profile and upload to app store.But am getting a message like this in "Code sign "   in   "build settings" of xcode5.0;
[image]

so i deleted all certificate from macbook and tried to create it from start and still it showing same for all profiles.Plz help me

Comment: Have you looked a bit lower down in XCode and seen that there is a separate section called Provisioning Profile below the Code Signing section.

Comment: i have selected correct one in that list

Answer (score 0):

Check your bundle id.
Go to developer.apple.com -> iOS Dev Center -> Identifiers -> App IDs 
and make sure that in XCode you wrote correct bundle id of your app.

Comment: let me re confirm this now

Comment: And make sure that in your keychain you have private & public keys of the distribution certificate that used by distribution provisioning profile